# EditText color cursor and marker

Tags: android, colors, textbox

I need to change all color of edittext from pink to blue, but the marker is always pink:

[image]

I'm use this code xml:

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/textcursor"
```

and

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size
        android:width="2dip" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need change colorControlActivated in style

**res/value/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/color_Black</item>
</style>
```

and use this in manifest

Answer (score 1):

one way is to add this line to your activity theme style

```
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/material_yellow_400</item>
```